# How to know whether "over" means during or more than?

Tags: ambiguity

**Over** has two meanings;

> : more than (a specified number or amount)
>   : throughout or during (a particular amount of time)

We can distinguish it in context but sometimes it's ambiguous for me.

For example

> It's been over a minute.

This kind of sentence is confusing for me. Above all, is it *preposition* or *adverb*?

If it's a preposition, I copied two examples from Merriam-Webster.

> I've been waiting for over an hour.
>   happening/occurring/developing over a period of 20 years.

According to the dictionary, it means *more than* in the first sentence but it means *during* in the second sentence. How to know whether **over** means *more than* or *during*?

Plus, what if second sentence was *happening/occurring/developing over 20 years*?

Comment: Potential responders might want to read what I answered to the same question here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122282/how-to-know-whether-over-means-more-than-or-during

Comment: This is an exact copy of another(his own) question! I'd say 'Good job' @Gustavson  I had posted already and had deleted temporarily for editing.

Comment: @frederick99 No problem. The asker may ask the same question here if (s)he wishes. As regards your answer, I don't think tenses will be very helpful, since "over" can be used with both meanings in many tenses.

Comment: @frederick99 Is the 'Good job' sarcasm?? I thought the two sites are independent and they explain differently. I wanted to refer both sites. BTW I'm worry that is this question proper for ELU?

Comment: @TingChoe Gustavson reduced the efforts the answerers would have to put in considerably. It wasn't in the least sarcastic. ;)

Comment: @TingChoe About ELU/ELL - opinions differ. ELU is "for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts" (see the [tour]). The difference in opinion is - broadly speaking - over whether the word "for" requires the *asker* to identify with that group. Simplistically, one might ask, "Would native speakers discuss such a question with other native speakers?"; if "yes", ask at ELU; if no, ask at ELL. In practice, the ELU community tends to give more leeway to questions that 'show their homework', which you have done. As for me, I welcome this question here at ELU.

Answer (score 1):

The two forms can largely be distinguished by the presence of the preposition "for".

The *more than type* of over is usually preceded by a "for".

> I have lived there for over five years.

Omitting the "for" conveys the sense of the action taking place *over* (during) the duration.

> It has been over a year since we last dated.
>
> The memories faded over the years.

Comment: Both the "lived there" and "living there" examples treat "over" as "more than". I think this is generally true for the form *[action] for over [time]*. Removing "for" allows the other interpretation.

Comment: @Lawrence Haha, you are telling me to revert to my original post (check edit) which _I thought_ was wrong. :D